# D3 Fetch Data from Python Function

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, flask

I have a Python function called `/CastCrew` that populates a form and returns the chosen .json file name.
This chosen json file is used to create the d3 graph but when I press “submit” after choosing a file, I get a messagebox to  “Open CastCrew” (When I open it I see the json file that I choose), It’s opening the file, the file isn’t being read by the D3.

This is the @app.route in Flask,

```
@app.route('/CastCrew', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def crew():
    form = CrewForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return current_app.send_static_file(os.path.join('Crews/', form.filename.data))

    return render_template('Crew.html', form=form)
```

And for the D3, I want to call the file like this –

```
d3.json("/CastCrew", function(error, graph) {
          force
              .nodes(graph.nodes)
              .links(graph.links)
              .start();
```

I have also tried url_for but it didn't make any difference

```
d3.json("{{ url_for('CastCrew') }}", function(error, graph) {
```

In [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-development-with-flask-fetching-data-with-requests/), the data is requested by calling the Python function in d3.

Why won’t this work for me?

Comment: It appears you're sending data back as an HTML template rather than json or a csv which d3 can consume. Take a closer look at the return formats in the flask example at your link.

Comment: Ooops I see you have two returns.Have you verified you're getting the proper format back?

Comment: @Radio yes when I open the file its the correct json file, in json format :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to post the form with JavaScript.  If you haven't overridden the submit event, the browser will just submit a normal request when you click the button, which will just return the file.

Additionally, `d3.json(url, callback)` makes a GET request, but the view sends the json file from a POST request.  Use `d3.json(url).post(data, callback)` to send a post instead.  You'll need to send the form data as well.

Here's an example of how to do that using JQuery.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    d3.json("{{ url_for('crew') }}")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .post($(this).serialize(), function(error, graph) {
            # show your graph
        });
});
```

If you're willing to use JQuery anyway, you might as well use it to make the post request rather than using D3 for that, as it's more straightforward.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("{{ url_for('crew') }}", $(this).serializeArray(), function(graph) {
        # show your graph
    });
});
```

[Here is a full working example of this code.](https://github.com/davidism/so_answers/tree/30379160)